# I want to choose one specific option when clicked on button and button should got disabled in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I have a 2 components in parent component I called child component, and in child I've 3 radio options and a button, what i want is, when i click on button, one specific option should select and button got disabled , but if i choose any other options then button got clickable again and that information i've to send back to parent component.

Now what is happening is click on button state is not updated for the first time. Means When i click the button it select the specific option and button got disabled but immediately it changes.

```
// parentComponent.js 

<ChildComponent optionValue="positive"/>

// ChildComponent.js

<Button disabled={sentimentButtonValue} onclick={approveSentiment(e,optionValue)}> Approved </Button>

<RadioGroup row name="row-radio-buttons-group">
{['Negative', 'Positive', 'Neutral'].map((item) => (
 <FormControlLabel 
   value={item}
   checked={checkedValue.toLowerCase() === item.toLowerCase()}
   control={<Radio />}
   label={item}
   onChange={changeSuggestedValue}
/>
))}

// logical code:

const [checkedValue, setCheckedValue] = useState('');
const [sentimentButtonValue, setSentimentButtonValue] = useState(false);
const {optionValue} = props;

const approveSentiment = (e, optionValue) => {
 setCheckedValue(optionValue);
 setSentimentButtonValue(true);
 console.log(sentimentButtonValue); // it should update the state and button got disabled
}

const changeSuggestedValue = (e) => {
 setCheckValue(e.target.value);
 setSentimentButtonValue(false);
}
```

Comment: When you update state, the component is re-rendered. So your `RadioGroup` is setting the checked value, which causes your `onChange` function to run and this sets your `sentimentButtonValue` back to false.

Comment: get the updated state everytime from child component to parent .?

Answer (score 0):

```
    useEffect(()=>{
    setSentimentButtonValue(true);
    },[checkedValue]);
```

Use useEffect hook to immediately get the updated state value of 'checkedValue' and to set the value for setSentimentButtonValue to 'true'.